# Woocommerce Bespoke Shipping Functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, transient

I have a WordPress site using WooCommerce with bespoke shipping functionality on. All it does is find the users shipping address and works out the distance between the customer and the depot, based on the mileage different shipping rules apply ie free shipping.

However I have the issue where if someone changes their shipping address in my account or through the backend and then goes to the checkout it still uses the old postcode. I am assuming this is cached in WooCommerce?

Here is the function which works out the distance, any help guys would be fantastic.

```
private function getDistanceAway() {
$distanceInMiles = null;
 $customer = new WC_Customer();

if($customer->get_shipping_postcode()) {
     $postcode = $customer->get_shipping_postcode();
 } else {
     $postcode = $customer->get_postcode();
 }

$fromPostcode = str_replace(' ', '', get_option('woocommerce_free_delivary_location_postcode'));
$toPostcode= str_replace(' ', '', $postcode);
$result = array();

//call google api
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$fromPostcode&destinations=$toPostcode&mode=car&language=en?EN&sensor=false&units=imperial";
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($data, true);

//calculate the distance away
if(isset($result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'])) {
    $distanceInMiles = intval(str_replace(' mi', '', $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']));
 }
    return $distanceInMiles;
}
```

Comment: See class_wc_shipping::calculate_shipping_for_package, I think it's the package_hash/wc_cache_helper.

Comment: Hi Progrock, Thank you for replying and for the advice. I am no PHP expert, I am trying to fix someone else's code. Do you no at all what I should do, or have any code which resolves the issue at all? Again thank you for your time.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224497/woocommerce-shipping